# Reading XML data in Netty 3.6.x

Tags: java, netty

I'm new to Netty and Java, and I'm trying to build up a simple Netty server that reads XML from a separate client (The client will keep sending me XMLs with a fixed format). For each XML, I need to do some processing.
I've looked at examples at echo-client/server and Object echo-client/server, and trying to decide which one I should model after, I'm not exactly sure if I should use a ChannelInboundByteHandlerAdapter or a ChannelInboundMessageAdapter?
And are there utility packages in Netty 3.6.x that handle demarshalling XMLs? How should I handle converting the raw data to XML?

Also, I don't know how stable 4.0.0.Beta is, since this app is not too complicated I wonder if it's just OK to use the 3.6.x.Final as it's probably more stable.

Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create XMLDecoder, XMLEncoder class(extends OneToOneEncoder) in Server program. 
And add ChannelPipeline as keys "decoder", "encoder".

In decode of XMLDecoder class, Convert received xml to custom class using JAXB. 
If a server send to client using xml, convert response custom class to xml string in encode method of XmlEncoder.

sorry, I have limited English proficiency.

Comment: Thanks! I think I got what I asked for.